# If Measure Value = Something Then X Else Y End

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 lines as measure values and I would like each line having their own % information but I cannot do that as a Text. Any workaround to get it to work?
[image]

**Tableau file sample:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1upehg61rg5psas/Percentage_on_success.twbx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try a dual-axis with your two line measures and put the bars as reference lines.  See [this](https://community.tableau.com/thread/157064) as an example.  You can't independently control the Text on "Measure Values" because it is treated as a single measure.

Comment: The scale should be of count but the display should be of percentage. Do you have an idea how it can be done with ref line?

Comment: The measure for your lines should be the actual values whereas the text can be the %.  This will make the scale be the count.